# Memory causing windows 7 applications to fail on mac (using parallels)

Tags: macos, memory, windows-7, parallels

I have been using Windows 7 applications within Mac iOS software for a few months (using Parallels), but recently it has stopped working. Every time I try to open a windows 7 application the application shows a broken, corrupted page that looks like static.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Parallels but this has been unsuccessful.

Thank you in advance.

Also, just before this happened my computer prompted that I was running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer and reset PRAM by holding down

'cmd+option+p+r'

After that try opening up the application again. If the issue persists, close the windows session and allow it to use some more memory and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I held down cmd+option+p+r while the computer was starting, but the problem still persists. How do I allow it to use more memory?

Comment: When you hold down the keys, your computer should restart again.                                                 While your windows session is closed, you can configure it's settings by locating the virtual machine configuration and selecting the Memory tab. Here's a link: http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22626.htm

Comment: I had to fully delete parallels, restart and then install parallels again - it works now, even though it's completely out of memory.